# Refresh ajax fetched content after x time

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

As the title says, I would like to update this ajax fetch every x time e.x. after 10 seconds

Tried a few things but didn't really worked out well. So that's why I ended up here..

so... how can I refresh the content after .x.. time?

content.php

```
<html>
<head>    
$.ajax({                                      
      url: 'form/contact.php', data: "", dataType: 'json',  success: function(rows)        
      {
        for (var i in rows)
        {
          var row = rows[i];          

          var bedrijf = row[1];
          var naam = row[2];
          var functie = row[10];
          var id = row[0];
          $('.table').append("<tr><td>"+bedrijf+"</td> <td>"+naam+"</td> <td style='font-size: 12px;'>"+functie+"</td> <td><a href='index.php?p=contact-edit&amp;id="+id+"'><img src='images/page_e.png' height='21' width='19'></a></td>")
        } 
      } 
    });


</head>
....
</html>
```

form/contact.php

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM contact");


$data = array();
while ( $row = mysql_fetch_row($result) )
{
  $data[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode( $data );
```

Thanks for your time

Comment: Did you look at the JavaScript Timing Events? Here's an example: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp

Comment: Did you try the `setInterval()`function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need an interval.

```
function doAjax() {
    //existing AJAX code here
}
doAjax(); //do AJAX on load
setInterval(doAjax, 10000); //...and every 10 seconds hence
```

Comment: the problem with this is that it's refreshing everything except the ajax... when I add a alert to function doAjax() {} it's refreshing every 10 seconds but the ajax stays the same.

Comment: If you put your current AJAX code inside my `doAjax()` function that WILL re-send the AJAX request every 10 seconds. Whether your AJAX callback, or the AJAX response, is what you require, is another question. On the simple point of how to repeat an action, though, what I provided achieves this.

Comment: Thank you, the problem was that I did not clear the table.. but now another problem, it's quite ugly that you see the content refreshing isn't it possible to do it in any other way?

Comment: Well if you clear the table in the AJAX callback, rather than before the AJAX request, the time between clearing and repopulation should be fairly imperceptible.

Comment: Ah thanks, I did it before the callback, so changed that to do it after the success, one other thing tho, wouldn't it kill my bandwidth? (if e.x. a lot of people will use it) if I refresh the content so much?

Comment: Well yes, that is a concern, although 10 seconds is not particularly frequent so it's not major. Web sockets may be a better option, but they're non-trivial to set up. A middleware solution like [Pusher](http://www.pusher.com) can help there, but it's still much more advanced than simple AJAX calls.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite vague, but to achieve the every 10 seconds refresh the above code should work if you wrap it in

```
setInterval(function() {
  // Fetch and update
}, 10000);
```

Be sure to empty your table upon each iteration.

Comment: I think you meant `setInterval`